# Como funciona realmente la funcion pop() en c#?

Tags: c#

esa es la pregunta, he mirado un poco la documentación de microsoft pero no me queda del todo claro, si alguien puede dejarlo claro con un ejemplo o dando más detalles lo agradecería. No quiero usar funciones sin saber como realmente funcionan.

Comment: Esto no es realmente una pregunta que cumpla con las normas de este sitio. Por favor lea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - más información sobre Stack Overflow en Español - [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si te refieres en el tema de listas y pilas supongamos que tienes 5 libros y quieres colocarlos uno sobre el otro;

Push() es cuando colocas un libro sobre la mesa, haces otro Push() y colocas otro arriba, etc.

Pop() es cuando quieres sacar un libro, pero solo de la parte de arriba debido al acomodo que los libros tienen.

Resumen: Push es agregar y Pop es sacar, pero de la parte superior.

Edit:Como comentan mas abajo esto es muy utilizado en el tipo de ordenamiento FILO (El primero que entra es el ultimo que sale), como el ejemplo de los libros, te recomiendo investigar sobre listas y pilas, son utilizadas en: Filas de banco, turnos, almacén de inventario, y muchas aplicaciones comunes etc.

Comment: Eso es el en caso de Pilas (stack), las listas usan Add y Remove, y tenes Pilas del estilo FIFO y FILO.